# How to make the img pinkish with an opacity of 0.5 on hover?

Tags: html

I have set of images and when hovered the image will fade(whitish fade) its color. But what I want is for it to be pink (pinkish fade) with an opacity of 0.5. I can't make it change its color, what I did is just the fading (whitish fade) of image when hovered.

```css
.img-overlay {
  position: relative;
}

.img-overlay img {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.img-overlay:hover img {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.middle {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

.text {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}

.img-overlay:hover .middle {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrappingimages">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 img-overlay"><img src="https://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/16590700?wid=520&hei=520&fmt=pjpeg" style="max-width:100%">
      <div class="middle">
        <div class="text">Pasta</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 img-overlay"><img src="https://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/16590700?wid=520&hei=520&fmt=pjpeg" style="max-width:100%">
      <div class="middle">
        <div class="text">Pasta</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Optional: clear the XS cols if their content doesn't match in height -->
    <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 img-overlay"><img src="https://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/16590700?wid=520&hei=520&fmt=pjpeg" style="max-width:100%">
      <div class="middle">
        <div class="text">Pasta</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 img-overlay"><img src="https://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/16590700?wid=520&hei=520&fmt=pjpeg" style="max-width:100%">
      <div class="middle">
        <div class="text">Pasta</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 img-overlay"><img src="https://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/16590700?wid=520&hei=520&fmt=pjpeg" style="max-width:100%">
      <div class="middle">
        <div class="text">Pasta</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Optional: clear the XS cols if their content doesn't match in height -->
    <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 img-overlay"><img src="https://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/16590700?wid=520&hei=520&fmt=pjpeg" style="max-width:100%">
      <div class="middle">
        <div class="text">Pasta</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/color-filters-can-turn-your-gray-skies-blue/

Comment: Maybe `background-blend-mode` is what you need: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-blend-mode

Answer (score 1):

Since filters are not compatible with all the browsers, alternatively you might want to set up your image as a background and create an overlay layer, which will only display on hover. It would be something like this:

```
<div class="box overlay red" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200?image=187');">
  <h1>Pasta</h1>
</div>
<div class="box overlay blue" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200?image=378');">
    <h1>Pasta</h1>
</div>
<div class="box overlay green" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200?image=339');">
    <h1>Pasta</h1>
</div>
<div class="box overlay orange" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200?image=329');">
    <h1>Pasta</h1>
</div>


body {
  text-align: center;
}
.box {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid grey;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-100-100-10.jpg);
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  position: relative;
}

.overlay:before{
  position: absolute;
  content:" ";
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display: none;
  z-index:0;
}

.overlay:hover:before{
  display: block;
}

.red:before {
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}

.blue:before {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
}

.green:before{
  background-color: rgba(0,255,0,0.5);
}

.orange:before {
  background-color: rgba(255,153,0, 0.5);
}

.box * {
    position: relative;
    /* hack */
}

h1 {
  color:white;
}
```

You can then play around with colors and opacity.
Check out how it would look on this [codepen](https://codepen.io/aska-g/pen/POqKbr).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of different css [filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) to achieve the results you're looking for. I made an example by fiddling around and tweaking the numbers until it looked pinkish.

```css
.img-overlay {
  position: relative;
}

.img-overlay img {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.img-overlay:hover img {
  -webkit-filter: sepia(1) hue-rotate(290deg) saturate(6) opacity(50%);
  filter: sepia(1) hue-rotate(290deg) saturate(6) opacity(50%);
}

.middle {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

.text {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}

.img-overlay:hover .middle {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrappingimages">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 img-overlay"><img src="https://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/16590700?wid=520&hei=520&fmt=pjpeg" style="max-width:100%">
      <div class="middle">
        <div class="text">Pasta</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 img-overlay"><img src="https://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/16590700?wid=520&hei=520&fmt=pjpeg" style="max-width:100%">
      <div class="middle">
        <div class="text">Pasta</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Optional: clear the XS cols if their content doesn't match in height -->
    <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 img-overlay"><img src="https://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/16590700?wid=520&hei=520&fmt=pjpeg" style="max-width:100%">
      <div class="middle">
        <div class="text">Pasta</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 img-overlay"><img src="https://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/16590700?wid=520&hei=520&fmt=pjpeg" style="max-width:100%">
      <div class="middle">
        <div class="text">Pasta</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 img-overlay"><img src="https://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/16590700?wid=520&hei=520&fmt=pjpeg" style="max-width:100%">
      <div class="middle">
        <div class="text">Pasta</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Optional: clear the XS cols if their content doesn't match in height -->
    <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 img-overlay"><img src="https://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/16590700?wid=520&hei=520&fmt=pjpeg" style="max-width:100%">
      <div class="middle">
        <div class="text">Pasta</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hmm i tried the sepia css earlier but the color is not equal. but thanks anyway ^_^

Comment: You have to do the `hue-rotate` on it as well, I know pure sepia is not pink :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.img-overlay:hover:after img {background:pink; opacity:0.5;}
```